# Why is Tshark memory usage increasing when I am not keeping information?

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I want to constantly monitor TCP data coming from a particular source.

I am using this command in a cygwin mintty xterm on a Windows server.

```
tshark.exe -i 5 -f "tcp port 1234" -T fields -e data | xxd -r -p
```

This works perfectly as I get a scrolling window of ASCII that is the data being sent to me. When that connection fails (which is what I am trying to debug) then the last data sent is shown in the cygwin window.

However, I notice that the Tshark memory usage is constantly creeping up and after a few hours is quite large.

What can I do about this? I would like to leave this running for several days.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try modifying your [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) command-line options to include the `-b files:N` option (and possibly other `-b` options as well for **duration** and/or **filesize**) to start a ring buffer.  Doing so will cause `tshark` to discard its internal state whenever it rolls to the next file in the ringbuffer.  Discarding state means freeing all memory associated with that state information, so at least in theory, you can capture forever.

For more information, feel free to read the Wireshark blog article, *["To Infinity and Beyond! Capturing Forever with Tshark"](https://blog.wireshark.org/2014/07/to-infinity-and-beyond-capturing-forever-with-tshark/)* by Evan Huus, one of the Wireshark core developers and the person responsible for implementing this feature to discard state information.

Comment: But I din;'t think I was writing to a file at all - am I. I am just outputting to the console.

Comment: `tshark` is still writing packets to a temporary file that will normally be automatically deleted after capturing has stopped, although sometimes not.  Either way, a file is being written to though.  You can find the temporary file by first running `tshark -G folders | grep "Temp"` to find the location of the temporary file folder.  If it's not there, then try looking in `$TMPDIR`.  The temporary filename will be of a form similar to, **wireshark_<interface>_<date><time>_<random>.pcapng**.

Comment: And even if tshark (or, rather, dumpcap) *weren't* writing to a file (for example, if it were writing to a pipe), and were doing a one-pass capture , there's still state that's retained for packet reassembly and request/reply matching (which it does as part of the dissecting process, which is the process that produces the field values that you're printing out to the standard output).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but instead of capturing into a file I was reading already captured packed from a large file (75GB). So, it looks like tshark has some internal bookkeeping table that is growing with a number of packages. The solution for me was the session reset option ( -M ), which looks like it truncates the internal state:

```
tshark -r /tmp/traffic.pcap -M 100000
```

Comment: Great tip! This keeps tshark's memory consumption low, without impacting its capturing efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't log packets with `-w` (but it does on its own , a file with `.pcapng` extension grows like hell in `/tmp/`)

And I solved these 2 issues:

1. Memory consumption
2. that internal pcapng file growing

.. by adding `-a duration:3600` + Autorestart of systemd service that runs my `tshark`. So after a hour `tshark` stops itself,  memory and the file in `/tmp/` are freed and `tshark` gets restarted by Systemd.